SQLAlchemy and SQLite Warnings with sqlalchemy-pysqlite3
I'm using SQLAlchemy version 2.0.36 with SQLite database. Here’s the code I have:
(python)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Text, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "People"
    person_id = Column("person_id", Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column("first_name", Text)
    lastname = Column("last_name", Text)

    def __init__(self, personid, firstname, lastname):
        self.person_id = personid
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

person = Person(123, "hi", "bi")
session.add(person)
session.commit()

I encountered issues when running this code on different SQLite versions:
On SQLite version 3.7.17, the code runs without issues.
On SQLite version 3.26.0, I receive the following error:
dbapi_connection.create_function(
sqlite3.NotSupportedError: deterministic=True requires SQLite 3.8.3 or higher
This behavior seems counterintuitive, as I would expect the opposite: the code should fail on the older version and pass on the newer version.
I researched and tried using sqlalchemy-pysqlite3. Following the guidance from this link (https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-pysqlite3/), I updated my engine creation line to:
engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite3:///:memory:")

This change prevented the previous error, but now I am facing two warnings:
First Warning:
SADeprecationWarning: The dbapi() classmethod on dialect classes has been renamed to import_dbapi(). Implement an import_dbapi() classmethod directly on class <class 'sqlalchemy_pysqlite3.SQLiteDialect_pysqlite3'> to remove this warning; the old .dbapi() classmethod may be maintained for backwards compatibility.
Second Warning:
SAWarning: Dialect sqlite:pysqlite will not make use of SQL compilation caching as it does not set the 'supports_statement_cache' attribute to True. This can have significant performance implications...
How can I safely resolve these warnings without making significant changes to my code?

I am unable to reproduce your issue with SQLAlchemy 2.0.36 and Python 3.13.1 (which uses SQLite 3.45.3).

My previous comment was re: SQLAlchemy's built-in sqlite:// support. The pysqlite3 package has not been updated for SQLAlchemy_2 and has not seen a release (or even a commit) in over five years.

"This behavior seems counterintuitive" - It also makes me wonder whether your app is using the version of SQLite that you think it is. Checking the value of engine.dialect.dbapi.sqlite_version may shed some light on that.
